# Change justify-content value when flex items overflow container

Tags: css, flexbox

Look at following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/27x7rvx6

The CSS (`#test` is flexbox container, and `.items` are its children):

```
#test {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  border: 2px solid red;  
}
.item {
  flex: 0 0 70px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: blue;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

There is a one line (`nowrap`) flexbox with fixed size items. The container has `justify-content` set to `center`. Because the items can't shrink and are together wider than the container they start to overflow.

My problem is that the content overflows both to the left and to the right. Is there a way to make the content justified to center but once it starts to overflow make it act like the `justify-content` property is set to `flex-start`, resp. make it overflow only to right of the container?

Comment: Nope....frankly, there is no method (using flexbox or not) to do this as it stands. CSS can't detect overflow like that. Maybe you could do something with an extra wrapper but it woud be funky

Comment: Yeah I know there is no direct way to do it. One way to solve it if  flexbox is not necessary is to use inline-blocks and text-align: center on the container, however I would like to solve this for flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```css
align-items: safe center;
justify-content: safe center;
```

ps **Safari** does not support these props

Comment: I had no idea this was a thing, thank you!

Answer (score 92):

`justify-content` is not the right approach to center because of the problem you describe.

Instead, I recommend [`auto` margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins). You can use them to center:

> Prior to alignment via [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) and [`align-self`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-self),
>   any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that
>   dimension.

And they behave as you want with overflow:

> Overflowing boxes ignore their auto margins and overflow in the [end](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-writing-modes-3/#end)
>   direction.

For example, you can set `margin-left: auto` to the first flex item and `margin-right: auto` to the last one, or insert `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.wide.test {
  width: 500px;
}
.test::before, .test::after {
  content: '';  /* Insert pseudo-element */
  margin: auto; /* Make it push flex items to the center */
}
.item {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="wide test">
  <div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that for preventing weird overflow, a `max-width: 100%` etc may be useful

Comment: @JosephMerdrignac yes it does

Comment: Does this example not show that it is not centering in the narrow version? Is there a way to center them when the inner elements are wider than the outer element?

Comment: What if the parent has no width?

Comment: I know this is an old response, but this has solved a truly annoying issue I've spent hours on... Basically, if I used justify-content: center it created flex overflow that wasn't contained by the overflow: scroll property. So you could scroll only partially. I am applying margin auto instead on before/after pseudo and it fixed the annoyance. 

I use Flex to create "pagination" with pages hidden using overflow: hidden. But I also want scrollbars if a specific page is too big and is currently in the view. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can also be achieved with flex-grow:1 on the pseudoelements in most cases.